# A formula about exponential map

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

We have exponential map from lie algebra $T_e(G)$ to $G$ , and
I want to prove :
$$
\exp(X+Y) = \lim_{n\to\infty} (\exp(X/n)\cdot\exp(Y/n))^n,\ \forall X,Y\in T_e(G)
$$
I can do it in matrix lie group, but I can't handle in general case.

$\exp(X)=\gamma_X(1)$ and $\gamma\in Hom(\mathbb{R},G)$ is the solution of:
$$
\begin{matrix}
\gamma(0)=e \\
(c\circ\gamma(t))'=F_X(\gamma(t))
\end{matrix}
$$
($c$ is chart form $G$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$)

$F_X(g)=\rm d$$l_g(X),g\in G$

and identify $T_g(G)=\mathbb{R}^n,g\in G$

I think the difficulty is:

No global chart for G is guaranteed to exist.

So I can't assume $\exp(X+Y)$ and $(\exp(X/n)\cdot\exp(Y/n))^n\ (\forall n)$ are in the same chart.

Answer (score 1):

It has been one year since I have posed this question.

Yesterday I have learned Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula. And this the answer.

We should consider Taylor expansion of $f(\exp(sX)\exp(tY))$, $f=\log:U\to T_eG$ is a locally defined vector valued $C^\infty$ function. I will write down the solution without go into details.

> Please refer to 
> [http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~wangzuoq/Courses/13F-Lie/Lie.html](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/%7Ewangzuoq/Courses/13F-Lie/Lie.html) (Lec 8-9 Thm 1.2) 
> Website is written in Chinese, but lecture note in English.

For 2 variable function $g:(s,t)\mapsto f(\exp(sX)\exp(tY))$.

We have $\frac{\partial}{\partial s}g(0,0)=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}s}|_{s=0}f(\exp(sX))=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}s}|_{s=0}\log(\exp(sX))=X$.

We can also conclude $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}g(0,0)=Y$.

Since $g$ is smooth, from Taylor formula:
$$
g(s,t)=g(0,0)+t\frac{\partial}{\partial t}g(0,0)+s\frac{\partial}{\partial s}g(0,0)+O(s^2+t^2)\\
=X+Y+O(s^2+t^2)
$$

Then
$$
\exp(sX)\exp(tY)=\exp(X+Y+O(s^2+t^2))
$$

Take $s=t=\frac{1}{n}$, since $\exp$ is continuous. Then:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(\exp(X/n)\cdot\exp(Y/n))^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\left(\frac{X+Y}{n}+O\left(\frac{2}{n^2}\right)\right)^n\\
=\exp(X+Y)
$$